# How to limit the iterations of a loop within a function?

Tags: python, function, loops

As my code currently runs, the limits on a number of incorrect entries isn't functioning properly.

I've tried having it run without the breaks, which has the iterations limited correctly, but then it doesn't seem to recognize when a valid input is given after an invalid one (it continues to loop in 'Enter a valid number'.

With the break in as it is now, invalid entries are not limited as they are supposed to be. A cursory search has not provided me with an answer, and I would appreciate guidance on how to improve my code's function so I can use these limitations (up to three incorrect entries, and then exiting on the fourth).

Before I split it into functions, it worked correctly.

```
max = 3
#conversion factors
MILES_TO_KM = 1.6
GALLONS_TO_LITERS = 3.9
POUNDS_TO_KG = .45
INCHES_TO_CM = 2.54

#main conversion function
def main():
    miles = int(input('Enter the number of miles: '))
    miles_to_kms(miles)
    fahrenheit = int(input('Enter the degrees in Fahrenheit: '))
    fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit)
    gallons = int(input('Enter the number of gallons: '))
    gallons_to_liters(gallons)
    pounds = int(input('Enter the number of pounds: '))
    pounds_to_kgs(pounds)
    inches = int(input('Enter the number of inches: '))
    inches_to_cms(inches)

#define conversion for miles
def miles_to_kms(miles):
    while miles <0:
        for counter in range(4):
            miles = int(input('Enter a valid number of miles: '))
            break
        else:
            print ('Too many invalid entries submitted.')
            exit()
            #I have an issue here (and in the others) where after one invalid entry is given it loops in invalid entries.
    kilometers = miles * MILES_TO_KM
    print(miles, 'mile(s) is equal to', kilometers, 'kilometers.')

#define conversion for fahrenheit
def fahrenheit_to_celsius(fahrenheit):
    while fahrenheit < 0 or fahrenheit >1000:
        for counter in range(max+1):
            fahrenheit = int(input('Enter a valid temperature: '))
            break
        else:
            print ('Too many invalid entries submitted.')
            exit()
    celsius = ((fahrenheit-32)*5/9)
    print(fahrenheit, 'degree(s) Fahrenheit is equal to', celsius, 'degree(s) Celsius.')

#define conversion for gallons
def gallons_to_liters(gallons):
    while gallons <0:
        for counter in range(max+1):
            gallons = int(input('Enter a valid number of gallons: '))
            break
        else:
            print ('Too many invalid entries submitted.')
            exit()
    liters = gallons * GALLONS_TO_LITERS
    print(gallons, 'gallon(s) is equal to', liters, 'liter(s).')

#define conversion for pounds
def pounds_to_kgs(pounds):
    while pounds <0:
        for counter in range(max+1):
            pounds = int(input('Enter a valid number of pounds: '))
            break
        else:
            print ('Too many invalid entries submitted.')
            exit()
    kilograms = pounds * POUNDS_TO_KG
    print(pounds, 'pounds is equal to', kilograms, 'kilograms.')

#define conversion for inches
def inches_to_cms(inches):
    while inches <0:
        for counter in range(max+1):
            inches = int(input('Enter a valid number of inches: '))
            break
        else:
            print ('Too many invalid entries submitted.')
            exit()
    centimeters = inches * INCHES_TO_CM
    print(inches, 'inch(es) is equal to', centimeters, 'centimeter(s).')

main()
```

Comment: "within a function" shouldn't matter... But you need a `return` statement, because print doesn't give you the result back

Comment: It just seemed weird to me because it was working before the program was split into functions. Print was working before I tried to add breaks, but I'll see what return does for me.

Comment: You're not using any returned values anyway, for example `cm = inches_to_cms(inches)`

Comment: as an aside, can you see that the data entry aspect of your conversion functions are all the same. So you could factor that out into a common function and avoid the duplication, perhaps passing it an applicable conversion function for each conversion. It will cut down your code a lot and make it easier to reason about and change.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: look at those while loops in your conversion functions (e.g. fahrenheit_to_celsius). They are all the same, so they could potentially be [refactored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) so that functionality is only implemented once and called many times. Just a suggestion, didnt mean to confuse if you are a beginner.

Comment: I think I'm seeing what you're saying now! I am pretty new to this, sorry for being a little slow on the uptake.

Answer (score 0):

You're immediately breaking on the first loop, so I don't think that's what you want.

Then your while loops are infinite as long as you're putting in invalid values

Try using this structure instead. Basically, try-except is easier to understand for most compared to a for-else that's only Python specific

```
unit = "miles"
conversion_rate = MILES_TO_KM
input_limit = 4 

units = None
for _ in range(input_limit):
    try:
        units = int(input('Enter a valid number of ' + unit +': '))
        if units < 0:
            continue # can't be negative 
        break # exit the loop if input can be made an integer 
    except ValueError:
        continue  # repeat the loop if it can't 
if units is None:
    exit() # out of inputs

return units * conversion_rate
```

Comment: So I shouldn't be keeping the 'while' in at all?

Comment: I don't see any reason for it if you only want to ask for input a fixed number of times

Comment: It's meant to keep negative values from being entered is all, since you shouldn't be able to convert those.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do with it, but again, your while loops are not counting against the invalid input counter , so it just repeats

Comment: Ah, okay. So is there another way to limit it while still have it count?

Comment: This answer already does limit it using a for loop. Are you required to use a while loop, or something?

Comment: No. Sorry, I didn't quite catch where it was limiting it in the loop. Now I see.